# android java intent putextra sms not working for jio4gvoice

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am trying to sent sms from my android app using
 `Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:"+number);
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        it.putExtra("sms_body", "Here you can set the SMS text to be sent");
        startActivity(it);`
and it is not working when i chose jio4gvoice

Comment: What is your android version??

Comment: Android 6.0 Marshmallow ,  4.3.1: Jelly Bean

Comment: This code not working in both devices??

Comment: this code is working but jio4Gvoice not supporting with this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this work

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

**OR**

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
```

**Note :** for second method you need **SEND_SMS permission**